# Abort current script on closing waitbar

Tags: matlab

I am using a waitbar like this:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');
for i=1:100, % computation here %
   waitbar(i/100)
   % other operation here
end
close(h)
```

I would like to stop this script if the user close the waitbar (clicks the `X` of the window), without having to add a Cancel button.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test whether `h` is a valid handle, and exit the loop otherwise. Insert the following into your loop:

```
if ~ishandle(h)
    break
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  try something like this :

```
if ishandle(h),
   close(h);
   % Your code here
else
    %waitbar has been closed by the user
    % call throw, return, or break
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: close(h) closes the waitbar not the script

Comment: Yes, the code is not complete in the sense, you basically check if the waitbar is closed or not. You follow that up with a `return`, or a `break` or `throw` statement depending on where you use it

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar: I fail to see how this will react to the window being closed by a user - you have to check whether the handle ceased to exist instead.

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar: then you should write `if ~ishandle(h)`

Comment: Hi, The answer is in no way complete. The idea was to check if the waitbar has been closed by the user. I am updating the answer.